# Android connecting to soap web-service with digest authentification using ksoap

Tags: android, web-services, http-status-code-401, ksoap, digest-authentication

I am having problems to get the Authorization headers from a PHP soap web-service with DIGEST authentification. (PHP client works correctly with the web-service).

I get error 401, but I cant find the header in the envelope. The headerIn field is empty.

I need to connect somehow to the web-service - get the headers (main problem) and then recreate the Digest authorization header (which is easy) and connect again to web-service with the authentification informations.

Any advice?

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(SoapProperty... soapProperties) {
    if(this.methodName.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("methodName is not specified");

    String response="";
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

    try{
        String SOAP_ACTION = this.namespace + "/" + this.methodName;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(this.namespace, this.methodName);

        for(SoapProperty s : soapProperties){
            request.addProperty(s.getKey(), s.getValue());
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(this.url);

        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = (String)envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        publishProgress(true);
    }

    return response;
}
```